# Jenkins build failed when compiling "mvn install" in the pipeline

Tags: java, spring, jenkins

The error message is:

```
wrapper script does not seem to be touching the log file in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/build-process@tmp/durable-e11111
if on extremely laggy filesystem try consider 
-Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL=86400)
```

I have added

```
-Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL=86400
```

in my jenkins file which resides in `/etc/default/jenkins` under JAVA_ARGS parameter but I got the same result.

My jenkins pipeline failing at:

```
stage("mvn install") {
    sh "mvn install"
}
```

Jenkins version: 2.250
Spring boot app: Spring version: 2.2.6.RELEASE

Please help!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I've tried updating the durable task plugin and ensuring the node has plenty of memory/disk space as well as the heartbeat check, nothing is working.